# Struct values change after allocating memory

Tags: c, struct, malloc

So I have some code which is eventually going to create a linked list of sentences which contains words and the punctuation that ends the sentence but right now I'm having a very peculiar issue:

```
struct sentence {
    char *words[10];
    char punc;
    struct sentence *next;
};

void split(char *buf, char *split[], size_t max) {
    char * token = strtok(buf, " ");
    int i = 0;
    while (token != NULL) {
        split[i] = token;
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    split[i] = NULL;
}

void read_sentence(struct sentence *a) {
    printf("> ");
    char str[30];
    scanf("%[^.!?\n]s", str);
    split(str, a->words, sizeof(a->words));
    char temp[1];
    scanf("%c", temp);
    a->punc = temp[0];
    a->next = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sentence *a = malloc(sizeof(struct sentence));
    read_sentence(a);
    printf("\nfirst contains: %s %s%c\n", a->words[0], a->words[1], a->punc);
    struct sentence *b = malloc(sizeof(struct sentence));
    printf("\nfirst contains: %s %s%c\n", a->words[0], a->words[1], a->punc);
}
```

Whenever I run this code the two print statements have different results, the first is correct but the second is empty. I'm at a complete loss as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second struct has nothing to do with this.

Your code invokes undefined behavior. You're loading a wrack of dangling pointers into your `words` member. All those pointers point to memory within the automatic variable `str` in the function `read_sentence`, which is gone as soon a `read_sentence` returns. The deferences for printing back in `main` therefore utilize dangling pointers and thus, UB

I could tell you to provide a dynamic solution to this (dynamic allocation of each word found using `strlen` + `malloc` + `memcpy`, or `strdup` if you step into the POSIX arena, or we can do it the easy way: make the memory `words` refers to tied to the sentence structure itself. I.e. Make a `str` that belongs to each `sentence`, then let `words` point to memory in its "sibling" member:

```
struct sentence {
    char line[80];   // <<=== here
    char *words[10];
    char punc;
    struct sentence *next;
};

void split(char *buf, char *split[], size_t max) {
    char * token = strtok(buf, " ");
    int i = 0;
    while (i < max && token != NULL) {
        split[i+] = token;
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    split[i] = NULL;
}

void read_sentence(struct sentence *a) {
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%[^.!?\n]s", a->line); // <<=== HERE
    split(a->line, a->words, sizeof a->words / sizeof a->words[0]); // <<=== HERE
    a->punc = getchar();
    a->next = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    struct sentence *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    read_sentence(a);
    printf("\nfirst contains: %s %s%c\n", a->words[0], a->words[1], a->punc);

    struct sentence *b = malloc(sizeof *b);
    printf("\nfirst contains: %s %s%c\n", a->words[0], a->words[1], a->punc);

    free(a);
    free(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Worth noting, this is probably more efficient than it first seems. Yes, each sentence gets its own line-buffer, but it doesn't need per-word allocations managing all those strings.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Re "*All those pointers point to memory within the automatic variable `str` in the function `read_sentence`*", The man page doesn't make it clear why this is, so I'll explain: `strtok` doesn't return new strings. It replaces the delimiters in the string being processed (`str`) with NUL characters, and returns a pointer pointing within that string.